# Document stating a person's ability to be an adoptive parent in Ireland

Tags: family-law, ireland, adoption, russia

> the opinion of a competent authority of the State of nationality of your husband, on his living conditions and his ability to be an adoptive parent; the permission of a competent authority of the State concerned to allow the adopted child to enter and permanently reside in the territory of that State

The above is a translated requirement placed upon a citizen of the Republic of Ireland trying to adopt a child from a country outside the EU. Which authority in Ireland could possibly provide such a document?

The source of the requirement is the State Department for the Protection of the Rights of Children in Russia.

Comment: This will be hard to answer if you don't provide the source of this requirement.

Comment: The source of the above requirement is the State Department for the Protection of the Rights of Children in Russia.

Answer (score 1):

They would first need to get a Declaration of Eligibility and Suitability which can be obtained from the [Adoption Authority of Ireland](https://aai.gov.ie/en/whats-is-intercountry-adoption.html).